# If $f:X \rightarrow X$ is a continuous bijection and $A \subseteq X$ is simply connected then $f(A)$ is simply connected

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Prove that:
>
> If $f:X \rightarrow X$ is a continuous bijection and $A \subseteq X$ is
>   simply connected then $f(A)$ is simply connected.

I know this means I have to find a homotopy between an arbitrary loop $(h)$ from a loop class in $\pi(f(A), f(x_0))$ and the trivial loop $e$, but I can't seem to find one.

I see that if $g$ is an arbitrary loop in a loop class of $A$, then $h=f \circ g$, but beyond this I can't find anything.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It's not true without some further assumptions on $X$ and/or $f$. Are there any further assumptions in place?

Comment: @DanielFischer Any counterexample?

Comment: Sure, @freakish. Let $X$ the topological sum of countably many copies of $[0,1)$ and countably many copies of $S^1$. Map one copy (this will be $A$) of $[0,1)$ to a copy of $S^1$ via $t \mapsto \exp (2\pi it)$, and shift everything else to another copy of the same space to get a continuous bijection.

Comment: @DanielFischer That's a very nice counterexample. You may want to post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with $f^{-1}$ is also continuous , but try to prove $A,f(A)$ are same homotopy type so if one of them simply connected then remainder is too . But I think your problem isn't always true . Note that a simply-connected set under a continuous need not be simply-connected .

Comment: How would you show this if $f^{-1}$ was also continuous?